# How to write using TeX

Tags: miktex, windows, documentation

I've downloaded MiKTeX as I'd like to write a Mathematical document using it (I've had some basic experience using LaTeX on the Maths Stack Exchange page as it requires everything like equations to be written using LaTeX I believe) but I'm not very good at computers and now I've downloaded it I don't know where to go from there. The download seems to have 1k+ folders and I have no idea where to go. Do I use a Word document and then somehow convert to TeX or does TeX have a special writing template I can go straight to to type in?

Thanks.

Comment: you might like to work through a tutorial such as https://www.learnlatex.org/ that will let you edit the sample documents inline in the page and get a feel for how it works before using your locally installed miktex system (and some tex editor such as texworks)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for that. What sample docs do you mean?

Comment: after the first couple of lessons there are two or three full (small) documents on each page that you can process with latex as given or edit and see the output

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understand now, thanks :) Thank you so much for providing that link, that's incredibly helpful of you!

Comment: You will probably want to use a program as an IDE to edit your TeX files.  There's a nice summary at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides. Word is definitely not in that list.

Comment: A basic start: (1) Open TeXworks (it should be already installed)  (2) Go to  File > New file from template (... or so) > Basic LaTeX documents > `article.tex` (3) Save the new file as `myfirsttex.tex`  or whatever (4)  Under File menu, click on the green triangle. That is all, if all packages were correctly installed, now you should have `myfirsttex.pdf` in the same working directory and a preview window at the right side.   Now study the comments of the template to understad a bit the syntax, experiment with the examples of this site, read a book ...

Comment: Just to be that guy who knows everything better: The maths input on stackexchange sites isn't using LaTeX but MathJax (though the syntax is LaTeX inspired and in most parts identical).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on a Windows machine (as you tagged this in your question), if you download MikTeX [here](https://miktex.org/download), and download the installer, you won't end up with a whole bunch of folders.

Just navigate to the downloaded file and open it.
Then it should guide you through the installation.